# Explicitly commit or rollback an MQ unit of work using Java APIs

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm working on a standalone Java application that GETs several messages from one MQ queue, processes the data contained within the messages and then PUTs a new message onto another MQ queue. One of the requirements is for the GET and PUT operations to be within the same unit of work and I am able to do this by specifying `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` and `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` get/put message options.

What I don't understand how to do using the Java MQ API is perform the MQCMIT and MQBACK operations to explicitly commit or rollback the MQ unit of work.

I've searched on the IBM MQ InfoCenter website and the JavaDoc but I can't find anything on the APIs used for committing and rolling back a unit of work.

The version of WebSphere MQ I'm using is 7.5 and I'm connecting to the queue manager using binding mode.

Would anyone be able to provide some example code showing how to explicitly commit or rollback the MQ unit of work using the Java MQ APIs or point me in the direction of the appropriate JavaDoc page please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic flow is that when you send the messages in a transaction it will hold the messages in a buffer until either a commit or rollback is called: if a commit is performed then the messages are sent, otherwise they are discarded.

Below is a sample from Novell using the JMS APIs which should be the same as WebSphere MQ if you're using the JMS API :

http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/txSession-1.htm

**UPDATE :**
Below is another question on StackOverflow that has code for committing / rolling back using the Websphere MQ APIs :

[java websphere MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426272/java-websphere-mq)

Comment: Thanks - I probably should have made it clear in the original question but this is a standalone application and isn't using JMS.

Comment: @PaulH Updated to include a Websphere MQ specific code sample.

Comment: +1 for finding the other SO question.  I'd forgotten about that one!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`commit()`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html)  method in the `MQQueueManager`.